# Numpy `random.choice` but using different weights each time we sample

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `(N, T+1)` array of weights. Its rows are normalized, meaning

```
np.array_equal(W.sum(axis=1), np.ones(N))
```

returns `True`.  Now I want to get `N` samples from `np.arange(T+1)` where to select the `i`th sample, I use the `i`th row of `W`. I could of course do this with a for loop:

```
import numpy as np

# Settings
N = 100
T = 20

# Create some normalized weights
W = np.random.rand(N, T+1)
W = W / W.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)

# Use a for loop to sample
samples = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    samples[i] = np.random.choice(a=np.arange(T+1), size=1, p=W[i, :])
```

However I was wondering if there is a way to do this already in numpy/scipy or perhaps using some other library. I am hoping with something like this:

```
# or perhaps a=np.repeat(np.arange(T+1).reshape(-1,1), N, axis=1).T
samples = some_function(a=np.arange(T+1), size=N, p=W)
```

Comment: Just a side note from the answer: the `W` matrix in your code can contain -ve numbers which will make the distributions invalid.

Comment: @AbhinavGoyal yep you're right, a typo in my MWE

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if there's inbuilt support in numpy for this explicitly but you can randomly sample from a uniform distribution and convert them to samples from your categorical distribution using the following:

```py
F = W.cumsum(axis=1)  # get the CDF of all distributions
r = np.random.rand(N)  # generate N random samples from U(0,1)
samples = np.argmax(F >= r[:, None], axis=1)  # convert all these samples to the categorical samples from respective distributions
```

All operations above are vectorized and `samples[i]` corresponds to a sample from `W[i]`. I'll try to explain why and how this works.

Assume you have a categorical distribution `p(i)`. To sample from it, you can use a random sample from uniform distribution `U(0,1)` and CDF `F(i)` such that, `F[i] - F[i-1] = p[i]`:

```py
# Assume p = categorical probability distribution i.e., p[i] = probability of i
F = p.cumsum()  # get the CDF
r = np.random.rand()  # a random sample from U(0,1)
s = np.argmax(F >= r)  # first index where F > r = a random sample from p - the categorical distribution
```

This works because `s` is such that `F[s-1] < r <= F[s]` (since `s` is the first index where `F > r`). Therefore, `P(this event) = P(F[s-1] < r <= F[s]) = (F[s] - F[s-1])/1 = p[s]`. Thus the probability of getting `r` in this range is the same as the probability of getting `s`.

In fact, using the vectorized form, you can now generalize the code to generate `K` samples for each `i`:

```py
K = 10000
r = np.random.rand(N, K)
samples = np.argmax(F[:, :, None] >= r[:, None, :], axis=1)
```

Here `samples[i]` correspond to `K=10000` samples from `W[i]`. You can also verify that the samples follow the categorical distributions we started from using following:

```py
for i in range(T+1):
    w = np.bincount(samples[i])/K  # get empirical distribution from samples
    error = ((W[i] - w)**2).sum()  # get the error in empirical and theoretical distributions
    print(error)
```

This will give you the error in empirical distributions and the distributions we started with (and the error will get smaller as you increase the number of samples - `K` which is what we expect to happen).

Let me know if this helps. Not sure how clear the explanation is though!